# Why do don't get the value from my object?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For some reason i'm not able to loop trough my object.
The data binding doesn't work at all. I have the exact same code in a different controller and there it works.

What's my mistake?

I have this controller:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state, $timeout) {
  var catId = $stateParams.id;

  firebase.database().ref("list/" + catId.toLowerCase()).on('value', function(snapshot) {

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.content = snapshot.val();
      $scope.test = $scope.content.name;
      console.log($scope.content);
      //returns object
      console.log($scope.test);
      //returns Barock
    })

  });
```

And this Markup:

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in content" class="animated lightSpeedIn">
  <a ui-sref="list({id: cat.name})"nav-transition="none"><div ng-style="{'background': 'url(' + cat.bgurl + ')','background-repeat': 'no-repeat','background-size': 'cover','display': 'block','width': '100%','height': '25vh' }" class="bgcat center">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1 class="title_data">{{cat.name}}</h1>
      <h4>{{cat.subtitle}}</h4>
    </div>
  </div></a>
</div>
<h1>{{test}}</h1> <!-- NO DATA SHOWN -->
```

This is the data which i get back:

[image]

My route for this view:

```
.state('list', {
      url: '/list/:id',
      templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
      controller: "ListCtrl",
      cache: false
    })
```

Comment: Didn't find any problem in your provided code. Are u sure your given markup's scope is the controller's one?

Comment: yes i am. the thing is, when i just display `<h1 class="title_data">{{cat}}</h1>` The whole array is shown. But when i go into the object i.e `cat.name` no data is shown. Could it be because the scope doesn't update beacuse i use $timeout again in this controller?

Comment: $timeout should call $apply implicitly so I don't think it is the reason. OIC.. looks like your `content` is an object but u are trying to iterate it as an array ? shouldn't it be an array according to your markup?

Comment: hmm i don't think so, because i used the same way in another controller and there it works well. Could you make an example how i should do it? When it's an object?

Comment: You can try replace `$scope.content = snapshot.val();` with`$scope.content = [snapshot.val()]` and see if that will work.

Comment: @MMhunter Thank you so much =) That worked!